# How can i get flexible variables Variables in a for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript

```
function checkwaffenticks() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    waffenid = document.getElementById(eval("waffe1c." + i + "."));
    alert(waffenid);
    tickkosten = waffen[waffenid].waffengeschwindigkeit;
    document.getElementById(eval("wgsc." + (i) + ".w1")).value = tickkosten;

    waffenid = document.getElementById(eval("waffe2c." + (i) + "."));
    tickkosten = waffen[waffenid].waffengeschwindigkeit;
    document.getElementById(eval("wgsc." + (i) + ".w2")).value = tickkosten;
  }
}
```

I want to address serveral ids but I don't want to write everything.

Is there a way to use `i` for addressing variables?

Comment: what you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

To create a string that represents an `id` from partly static and partly dynamic data, **just use plain string concatenation**.

The [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) operation is very dangerous, opens up big security holes in an application and is the source of your problem since it attempts to evaluate a string as JavaScript code and the strings you are generating don't represent any JavaScript. `eval()` should be avoided in all but the most edge of edge cases.

```js
function checkwaffenticks() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById("waffe1c." + i + ".").value = "test " + i;
  }
}

checkwaffenticks();
```

```html
<input id="waffe1c.0.">
<input id="waffe1c.1.">
<input id="waffe1c.2.">
<input id="waffe1c.3.">
<input id="waffe1c.4.">
<input id="waffe1c.5.">
<input id="waffe1c.6.">
<input id="waffe1c.7.">
<input id="waffe1c.8.">
```